# How to transfer local database table's data to remote database tables using vb.net with SQL Server

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a local SQL Server database with many tables. I need to transfer data to a remote SQL Server database using vb.net, and task should be run every 2 hr from application. How is it possible to do this? Please suggest the best way for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is replication. i don't know the possibilities in `SQL Server` but it works great in `mysql`. if you enables the replication in two database(Master- Slave) what ever be the changes you have made in the master will simultaneously in the slave. there is possibilities for [Bi-Directional Replication in MySQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/870358/Bidirectional-Replication-in-MySQL).

SQL Server provides various [types of replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152531.aspx)  to extend the possibilities. this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/715550/SQL-Server-Replication-Step-by-Step) helps you to establish replication in Sql Server

Comment: Thanks , it really helpful for me.